# nopCommerce: customizing models

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, nopcommerce

I am making all objects to inherit from  `IEntity<T>` instead of BaseEntity. This is to enable me implement repository pattern for data retrieval. However, I ran into a snag when customizing

```
public virtual TPropType GetLocalized<TEntity, TPropType>(TEntity entity, Expression<Func<TEntity, TPropType>> keySelector,
        int? languageId = null, bool returnDefaultValue = true, bool ensureTwoPublishedLanguages = true)
        where TEntity : BaseEntity, ILocalizedEntity
```

I think TEntity is supposed to implement  `IEntity<T>`

How can I customise the above to make the code work well...

Comment: What compile error are you receiving?

Comment: var bcc = _localizationService.GetLocalized(messageTemplate, mt => mt.BccEmailAddresses, languageId); throws error " cannot convert from 'TPropType' to 'string'" and "Cannot implicitly convert type 'T' to 'TPropType' "

Comment: Which version of nopcommerce are you using?

Comment: nopcommerce version 4.1